# Characteristic polynomial determines three reducible elements (line pairs) in the pencil of plane conics

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry

Let $\eta_i,0\leq i\leq 4$ be 4 variables and $\eta_0 x^2+4\eta_1 x^3y+6\eta_2 x^2y^2+4\eta_3 xy^3+\eta_4 y^4$ be the associated quadratic form. Consider $U=x^2,V=2xy, W=y^2$. Then the quadratic form transforms into $$\eta_0 U^2+2\eta_2UV+\eta_2(V^2+2UW)+2\eta_3VW+\eta_4W^2=0\quad (1)$$ and there is an additional relation $$4UW-V^2=0\quad (2)$$ Denote by $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ the associated quadratic forms of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

Consider $\det(Q_1+\lambda Q_2)=0$ for solving $\lambda$ (i.e. $(1)+\lambda(2)=0$ is associated quadratic form). Then plugging $\lambda$ in $(U,V,W)^T(Q_1+\lambda Q_2)(U,V,W)$, one will see the polynomial splits into linear factors.

$\textbf{Q:}$ Why does the polynomial splits into linear factors? I could see there is a coordinate transformation s.t. $Q_1+\lambda Q_2$ is effectively (2 by 2 matrix) $\oplus\ 0$ by $\det(Q_1+\lambda Q_2)=0$. That 2 by 2 is quadratic as well. Hence it reduces to quadratic of 2 variables which splits over complex number. This seems very cumbersome.

Ref. *An Introduction to Invariants and Moduli*, Mukai, Remark 1.26 of Chapter 1, Sec. 3(b), pg 28.

Comment: It won't show me page 27, but it does show pages 26 and 28. I recognize the 3 by 3 image of an element of the 2 by 2 modular group. Suggest you look up W. Magnus, Noneuclidean Tessellations and their groups. The relevant material goes back to a German book by Fricke and Klein, (1897), Lectures on Automorphic Forms. F+K has recently been translated into English. (I have a cheap reprint of the 1897 original).

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=oUcMZbiM7eAC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=Moduli+and+Invariants,+Mukai&source=bl&ots=t-pwDG3mEU&sig=291gbKHxWHX38NvoMZE1Zqb-jCw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwix4u7a_8DfAhUnwVQKHYMqBHQQ6AEwCHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=Moduli%20and%20Invariants%2C%20Mukai&f=false

Comment: https://books.google.com/books?id=H5kLAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=Vorlesungen+%C3%BCber+die+Theorie+der+automorphen++Functionen&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAGoVChMIscb4rNvYxgIVSCiICh3qMwQX#v=onepage&q=muesli&f=false

Comment: magnus; the material I meant is on page 23, not shown here: https://books.google.com/books?id=iLkzandfCc8C&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: @WillJagy I can check chpt 3 of Magnus's book. Thanks.